# How to make Angular ignor errors during compilation

Tags: angular, function, build, compilation

I have a function that I use to pass data to an API in javascript. the function uses the API javascript link I placed at the header of the html page.

Now I'm rebuilding the entire system using Angular, the function is been marked as error and I'm unable to build the project using "ng build --prod". Is there anyway I can make the compiler know that the function is from the API link I placed in the index.html page,or is there anyway I can make the compiler to ignore the error and build the project. Here is the function "getPaidSetup()" that connects with the api link.

```
....
....

  doSomething(){
      // the following getpaidSetup() function is throwing an error "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'getpaidSetup'."
      var x = getpaidSetup({ // this is dependent on the link placed in the index page
          customer_email: 'useremailishere@domain.com',
          amount: 1000,
      });
  }
 ----

Anyone with idea on how I can build the project or make the compiler ignore the error? Thanks in advance
```

Comment: you're saying getPaidSetup is on the window object?

Comment: may be try (window as any).getpaidSetup

Comment: yeah, typescript is saying that `getPaidSetup` is not defined on this class. you can call window explicitly like above comment, but in angular it's more usual to put a call in a service class and leave index.html alone.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Dan Oswalt. It worked for me. Thanks so much, you've saved me from headache. But can you throw more light on the (window as any)?

Comment: Answered below as official answer (too long as a comment! and it's basically the answer the helped you solve the thing)

Answer (score 1):

This is an explanation of the comment that helped the OP out, suggested by @Vikas, which was to try `(window as any)` in order to call a function that was defined on index.html. It was too long for a comment, and it basically solved what the OP was looking for.

The answer is 1) namespaces and 2) typescript

If you are in the global namespace and you define a function, it will become a property of `window`. While in that global context, you don't have to explicitly say `window.getPaidSetup()`, you can say `getPaidSetup().

In Angular, you are almost always defining functions in a "class", which is its own namespace. If you want to call something on the `window`, you will need to say it explicitly. `window.getPaidSetup()`.

BUT, we're using typescript, which should complain if you say `window.getPaidSetup()` (try it out). Why? Because typescript doesn't know that you extended the window object type with a new function. The quick and dirty way to make it be quiet is to cast it as `any`, which means don't worry about the strict type. You can cast in place with `(window as any).getPaidSetup()`.

Here's a good blog post I found with more than you wanted to know! https://mariusschulz.com/blog/declaring-global-variables-in-typescript